# Default style for custom view

Tags: android

I create custom view.
Code here:

```
class MyView
@JvmOverloads
constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = R.style.myStyle) :
    LinearLayout(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

    init {
        View.inflate(context, R.layout.my_view, this)
    }
}
```

Layout here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:style="@style/my_style">

    ...

</merge>
```

Style here:

```
    <style name="MyStyle">
        <item name="android:paddingTop">8dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingBottom">8dp</item>
    </style>
```

I add my view to activity layout:

```
<MyView       
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"       
            android:background="#00ff00" />
```

And my view has no padding top/bottom from MyStyle.
But if I add view programatically, all ok:

```
v = MyView(ContextThemeWrapper(this, R.style.myStyle), null, 0)
v.setBackgroundColor(resources.getColor(R.color.my_color))
rootView.addView(v)
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried adding 'padding' in your View?

Comment: I don´t sure about this... you are using merge, so in your custom view you need to inflate the view attaching to the root, it is ok, and if you apply your padding programatically in the custom view init it will works fine, i´m sure... but using the deffStyleAttr, maybe you need to declare it using a parent theme, i supossed that reading the doc:  @param defStyleAttr An attribute in the current theme that contains

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **`defStyleAttr`** is a theme attribute and not a style.

You have to define in your `attrs.xml`:

```
 <attr format="reference" name="myAttr"/>
```

Then in your app theme:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="...">
    <item name="myAttr">@style/MyStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="MyStyle">
    <item name="android:paddingTop">8dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">8dp</item>
</style>
```

Finally:

```
class MyView
@JvmOverloads
constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = R.style.myAttr) :
    LinearLayout(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {
```